# Restrict the $root from console in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In my site, I can get all the information of login user and authentication from $root variable. From console only I can change my authentication. But, I want to restrict that thing to provide security to my site.

Need Suggestions what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you don't need to pass all the info from the logged user at all..

Comment: Your user should have a token that is bind to user account for limited time, the token should represent the user instead of user name etc.

Comment: @Icycool  But how to stop the access of $root variable in browser console?

Comment: Everything is accessible in browser console, even if you try to encrypt it, the user can still find the encryption algorithm and key from your source code. But a remote hacker should not have access to your browser console?